# Create Controller with read/write actions using EF from linq class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

code:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace explorer.Models
{
    [Table(Name = "Meta")]
    public class MetaD
    {
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
        [Column (IsPrimaryKey=true)]
        public int MId{ get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public DateTime? Updated { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public Boolean? Active { get; set; }
    }

    public class mContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<MetaD> MetaData { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The above works but when running it gives the error: The model backing the 'mContext' context has changed since the database was created. Either manually delete/update the database, or call Database.SetInitializer with an IDatabaseInitializer instance. For example, the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges strategy will automatically delete and recreate the database, and optionally seed it with new data.

Answer (score 0):

Find/Replace `(IsPrimaryKey=true)` to `, Key`

Comment: actually rather then replacing it, I added [key] to it. and it worked. however when i load the index view I get this error now: The model backing the 'mContext' context has changed since the database was created. Either manually delete/update the database, or call Database.SetInitializer with an IDatabaseInitializer instance. For example, the DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges strategy will automatically delete and recreate the database, and optionally seed it with new data.

Comment: The erro message is telling you exactly what you need to do. I recommend you follow the EF Code First walkthrough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj193542.aspx